# Should access always be the lowest?

Tags: java, modifier

Should I always use the lowest possible access level? If something can be package-local and is protected, should I make it package-local?

(Or, generalizing: if something could have a "lower" access level than it has, should it be lowered?)

Is this a bad practice or (just crazy || mega-enterprisey) stuff?

Comment: thats up to you although, its nice to build in mind of making shareable modularized code which benefits from access controls.

Answer (score 0):

A general good practice is to not give something more access than it needs. So to answer your question, yes, if something is protected but does not ever need to be extended then you should declare it package-private.